# How do i filter out duplicate rows in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to include only unique rows in a query in sql? I'm working with flight information for a homework problem, and and I can't figure out how to perform aggregation functions on only unique rows. I need to do this because i have to return things like average distance and delay time, but there are duplicate rows. For example, if this were my data:

```
FLIGHT  DISTANCE    DELAY
1230      200         5
1230      200         5
1230       5          6
```

and i used select distinct on a flight number, it would not capture the unique third row. Basically i need a way to say "Include only rows with all unique values" in my query, but only return 2 columns

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to all columns in the `SELECT` so `SELECT DISTINCT FLIGHT, DISTANCE, DELAY` will give you the results you want. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPSFsRbYV72vFKQ7gDMAGD/0

Comment: Just wondering, but is it the homework that asks to aggregate on only the unique records?  Or based on your observation that the sample data has dups?  Anyway, one could also group twice.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `distinct` to remove the duplicates in your result.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can achieve this is as follows

```
select * -- you can do apply aggregation e.g. avg(a.distance) functions here
from (
   select distinct FLIGHT, DISTANCE, DELAY from <table_name>
)a
;
```